# 100mn rows of "events" with 30 or so attributes, want to understand what affects one particular attribute - how? which software?

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, regression-strategies

I have about 50-100 million rows of data of interesting "events". Each of these rows has about 32 attributes. One of these attributes is how much money we made :-)

What's the best way to make sense of this data? I've heard that Decision trees might be a great way to understand this.

To be clear, I don't have prediction needs for the future, I just want to know which attributes are highly correlated with the money being made.

I would also like to know what kind of software should I be using to do this? Should I create a SQL database? My current data is in CSV, I've converted it to JSON.

Also, is this a machine learning problem?

Comment: You should get some samples from the dataset. For example, separate 10000 rows and test some techniques on it before using them on the whole data. Regarding the methods, you probably don't need anything "fancy" right now, just getting the correlation matrix should be enough to start. Also, it isn't a machine learning problem by some definitions (that means: don't worry about it too much).

Comment: Some regression methods should do. Make an analysis plan, including setting of various samples from the data for initial exploration, model selction, estimation of final model, and evaluation of final model. Do not reuse data in any of the steps (with so much data there is now problems with this).